# Maven wsdl generation memory consumption

Tags: java, maven, memory, wsdl

During maven build, I have also wsdl generation process that generate sources from wsdl file**s**. During this generation java (maven) process can take about 850 Mb. Is there way to reduce this consumption?

Comment: We need a lot more detail to provide a useful answer. Please start by posting the WSDL file in question; it may be possible to identify particular issues that are triggering such large memory consumption.

Comment: Sorry but there is a lot of wsdl files, about 10-15 projects and one wsdl per project.

Comment: Why would you like to reduce the memory consumption? Did errors occur or what is the reason? This is only done during the build phase of the project.